# Upgrading Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

I am upgrading Visual Studio and it's 14 gigs in size. My worry is with my internet connectivity.

If my connection fails, would it start afresh or continue with what's not loaded in the system?

I know this isn't a programming question but I would appreciate your help.

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio?  I know there are offline installers and ISOs available for the Pro, and Enterprise versions.  I would expect one also for the Community Edition.  Even if not, I would expect the installer to resume the download.

Answer (score 0):

I can't give you a definitive source, but in my experience the VS installer simultaneously downloads and installs its components. The already downloaded components are locally stored (I think even in the directory from where you start the installer) and will be re-used if you cancel the installer and restart it. That way you could even share the downloaded files among multiple computers.

However, as state in the comments, there are offline installers available. If your connection is wonky, the web installer might even be a better bet since your ISO or whatever may or may not be resumed if partially downloaded.

Comment: I was using web installer tot install it and left it overnight. Now I have finished and got this problem where templates like the portable class library